# How to add PHP array to JS array in Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, highcharts

All I want is to be able to add this simple PHP array to display in the X axis. It's not wanting to display my content at all and I'm not understanding why.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php 
        $array = array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    js_array = new Array(<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>);
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: js_array
            }
```

Comment: won't solve your problem, but you should use `[]` instead of `new Array` - the latter creates an unneeded object wrapper

Comment: Try `js_array = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>');`

Comment: I'm getting no luck with that. I'm still getting a blank screen.

Comment: did you check the error log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We seem to be overcomplicating matters here...

change this:

```
           js_array = new Array(<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>);

           ...

           xAxis: {
                categories: js_array
            }
```

to this:

```
xAxis: {
   categories: <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Comment: It wont help, you cant use JSON-encoded strings directly. You need to parse them first

Comment: No luck, still getting a blank screen.

Comment: after adding the php array into js did you try to check the value inside your array ? it can be some other issue as well. try console.log(js_array) and see weather the values are there

Comment: Yeah that seems to be an issue as well. It's not wanting to print out the values.

Comment: There is a major issue going on. I've commented out everything and tried just echoing out the php. Not even that works.

Comment: @tabias **did you check your php error log?** if you're getting a white screen, there's almost guaranteed to be an error in there that will tell you exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: try var_dump($array) and tell us the output

Answer (score 0):

An JSON Object is not the same as an js array. You would need to parse the code first. JSON.parse() or eval() might help parsing.

```
js_array = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>');
```

as @user1477388 commented correctly

Comment: +1 but `eval` is unnecessary. use `JSON.parse`, which was designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: I know, but eval is not as bad as everybody thinks. Just in case JSON.parse() is not availible (its only supported in *most* browser), eval() works the same way.

Comment: if `JSON.parse` is not available, standard practice is to just include crockford's json2.js library. `eval` will work fine for *this* case (as there's no user input), but recommending it as a general solution is **not** a good idea.

Comment: there's no need to parse anything - you can use the json_encoded array directly as the categories array.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at the article http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database which describe hwo to use array.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me like this:

for **categories** :

```
categories: [<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){ echo "'".$name[$i]."'"; echo ",";} ?>],
```

for **data**:

```
data: [<?php echo join($age, ',') ?>]
```

Note that ***$name is a string array*** and ***$age is an integer array***. Also keep in mind that this code worked with me when I imbedded the php,Sql query in the same page.