# Highcharts add several series with PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to display some database informations, so when I use one series I haven't any problems, but when I want to add several series on my chart, it's a little bit difficult.

First my PHP script :

```
foreach ($informationslier as $keyFille => $fille) {
    $grafData = array();

    foreach ($fille['information'] as $keyInfos => $information) {
        $mois = $information['created']->format('m');
        $mois = $mois - 1;

        $timestamp = strtotime($information['created']->format('j').'-'.$mois.'-'.$information['created']->format('Y'));
        //Multiply by 1000 to get seconds in js
        $timestamp = $timestamp * 1000;
        $grafData[$keyInfos] = array($timestamp, (float)$information['valeur']);
        //$grafData[$keyInfos] = implode(', ', $grafData[$keyInfos]);
        //$grafData[] = "[Date.UTC(".$information['created']->format('Y').','.$mois.','.$information['created']->format('j')."),".$information['valeur']."]";
    }

    $tabInformationsData[$keyFille]['name'] = 'Evolution '.$fille['titre'];
    $tabInformationsData[$keyFille]['color'] = '#FFA020';
    //$tabInformationsData['infos'][$keyFille]['data'] = array();

    //$implodeGraf = implode(',', $grafData);
    $tabInformationsData[$keyFille]['data'] = $grafData;
}
```

The php script return me something like this :

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
            [name] => Evolution pourcentage
            [color] => #FFA020
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1451084400000
                            [1] => 17.00
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1451170800000
                            [1] => 19.00
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1451257200000
                            [1] => 14.00
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1451343600000
                            [1] => 6.00
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I send this array to my view and I do this :

```
series: {{ graphique | json_encode() | raw }},
```

But in the HTML, the rendering looks like this and doesn't work :

```
series: [{
    "name":"Evolution pourcentage",
    "color":"#FFA020",
    "data":[[1451084400000,"17.00"],[1451170800000,"19.00"],[1451257200000,"14.00"],[1451343600000,"6.00"]]
}],
```

I don't know why it doesn't work... I try to multiply by 1000 the timestamp or not but nothing work.
So, how can I display all my series ?

**EDITED**

Work by passing all date to timestamp and adding (float) before all the values... I edited my post with the response.

Thanks

Comment: Parse json array. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064226/how-to-add-php-array-to-js-array-in-highcharts

Comment: Hey, thanks but I found a solution : `{{ graphique | json_encode() | raw }}`, I still get a problem with two quotes in each of my data arrays, i updated my post.

Comment: Removing quotes won't be enough. You are trying to use `Date.UTC()` which is JavaScript function, so it always will be returned as string by PHP. Instead you should calculate timestamp in PHP, so returned will be number. Then there should be: `[0] => [1453852800000, 20.00]`, `[1] => [1453939200000, 30.00]` ... etc.

Comment: In the PHP you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function which returns unix timestamps. Please note that you need to mutliply all unix timestmaps by 1000 to have javascript format.

Comment: I tried to use timestamp and multiply them by 1000 for the javascript, the array of series seems good, but nothing appear on my chart...I edited my first post again.

Comment: Ok it works by passing (float) before all the values...

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

- iterate on your `{{ my_array }}` twig variable
- use only unicode character for your JSON : [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)